# How do I statically link sqlite to my android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, static-linking

I need to statically link the 3.6.2 version of SQLite against my android application due to a bug that affects the dynamic library bundled with Android < 2.2. I've already compiled and installed 3.6.2 on my development machine, but I'm not sure how I go about linking it to my Android app (developing with Eclipse).

I'm not familiar with building and compiling options, so if someone could walk me through step-by-step, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. My Android app is in Java.

Comment: You can't static link with Java.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite builds "out of the box" using the Android NDK. Get the NDK, create a .mk file for SQLite with the options you desire and build.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting errors when I run the ndk-build script. I copied the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files to my project's jni folder, created a simple .mk file and ran ndk-build. It returned with compilation errors about some undefined references. Sorry, I'm a complete noob when it comes to compiling. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the errors your getting, it's hard to respond here.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting:

Compile thumb  : sqlite3 <= ###/eclipse/workspace/MyProject/jni/sqlite3.c
###/eclipse/workspace/MyProject/jni/sqlite3.c: In function 'unixDlError':
###/eclipse/workspace/MyProject/jni/sqlite3.c:26415: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
SharedLibrary  : libsqlite3.so
###/eclipse/workspace/MyProject/obj/local/armeabi/objs/sqlite3/sqlite3.o: In function `unixDlSym':
###/eclipse/workspace/MyProject/jni/sqlite3.c:26442: undefined reference to `dlsym'

Comment: It looks like you need to link in libdl. E.g. in your LOCAL_LDLIBS:
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -ldl

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add the binary to assets and then unzip to /data/data/ and exec it from there.